# Drupal templating not working properly

Tags: php, templates, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-templates

I am trying to set up templates for specific pages in Drupal.  The handbook says that PHPTemplate looks for these templates in "descending order":

```
page-node-edit.tpl.php
page-node-1.tpl.php
page-node.tpl.php
page.tpl.php
```

However, the only one of these that works for me is the last one.  This is the one I don't want to work, as it works for every page, and I need to set up templates for particular pages.  Anyone know why this is working this way?  On top of that, it's causing me a huge headache to get to the admin page as well.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, this was the handbook from Drupal 6.  Must use double dashes in Drupal 7.  Ex. page--node--3.tpl.php.

Sorry for any confusion, maybe this will at least help someone else.